# Calculating $\inf \left\{\exp((-1)^nn)\right\}$ via the $\epsilon$-definition?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Define the infimum of a set. For $S = \left\{\exp((-1)^nn): n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$, find $\inf(S)$ and prove your claim.

**Definition:** $w = \inf(S)$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there's $x_{\epsilon} \in S$ such that $x_{\epsilon} < w+\epsilon$.

**Claim**: Since $e^{y} > 0$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $S$ bounded below by $w=0.$ We claim $0 = \inf(S)$.

I'm stuck on the proof because for constructing such $x_{\epsilon}$ I run into the problem of having $\log(-\epsilon)$ when working backwards from $e^{-2k-1}> -\epsilon$, and which doesn't make sense in $\mathbb{R}$ because $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: You have the definition wrong (even if you correct the typo).

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for checking this! I've fixed the definition and tried to correct the 'proof' accordingly as well. Do you mind having a look again, please?

Comment: You corrected the typo. But as I wrote, fixing this still leaves an incorrect definition.

Comment: @zhw. I corrected the definition too, no? $x_{\epsilon} > w-\epsilon$ where $ w$ is the infimum. The problem I've faced now is that when I'm working backwards from this to construct $x_{\epsilon}$ I run into $\log(-\epsilon)$ which doesn't make sense as $\epsilon > 0$. Or do I've to use a definition completely different to the one I was trying to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$, we need to show that there exists some $n$ so that:
$$e^{(-1)^nn} - 0 <\epsilon$$
Clearly if $n$ is odd then,
$$e^{(-1)^n n} = e^{-n} <\epsilon$$

So picking any odd $n>\log(\tfrac1\epsilon)$ will work. It follows that $0$ is a limit point of $\left\{e^{(-1)^n n} : n=0,1,\dotsc\right\}$, but to see that it is the infimum simply note that $e^{(-1)^n n} > 0$.

Comment: No you want to show there are points as close to $0$ as possible, i.e., for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $n$ such that  $\left|e^{(-1)^n n} - 0\right| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Yeah, realised that after I posted it (sorry). You know, I'm still not certain of the error in my earlier attempt (I edited out). For any $\epsilon > 0 $ we can take $x_{\epsilon} = \exp(-2k-1))$ for $k > \frac{1}{2} (\log(1/\epsilon)-1).$ Then we have:

$2k > \log(1/\epsilon)-1 \implies 2k+1 > -\log(\epsilon) \implies -(2k+1) < \log(\epsilon) \implies \exp(-(2k+1))< \epsilon.$

 Thus $x_{\epsilon} < \epsilon = 0+\epsilon $.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is *half* of the definition of the *supremum*, so let's start there.

"Infimum" and "supremum" are terms for the greatest lower bound and least upper bound of a set.  To keep the terms straight, remember infimum/supremum $\Leftrightarrow$ inferior/superior $\Leftrightarrow$ below/above; so "infimum" has to be a lower bound and "supremum" has to be an upper bound.

So what does "$w$ is the greatest lower bound of $S$" actually mean?

- First, $w$ has to be a lower bound of $S$; in other words, $w\le x$ for every $x\in S$.
- Second, any greater number ($w+\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$) is *not* a lower bound of $S$; for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $x\in S$ where $x < w+\varepsilon$.

(I've never had much luck memorizing $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definitions directly myself; understanding the ideas and generating definitions on the fly has always been much more effective.)

On the specific set $S=\{1, e^{-1}, e^2, e^{-3}, e^4, e^{-5}, \ldots \}$, your intuition that $\inf S = 0$ and your idea of using logarithms to prove it are both correct, but you need to consider $\log\varepsilon$ for arbitrarily small (but *positive!*) values of $\varepsilon$.

Hope this helps!